# Why does "instance.send(:initialize, *args, **kwargs, &block)" fail only from within Class#new?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.2

I've been stuck on this for quite a while now. Take a look at this:

```
class SuperClass
  def self.new(*args, **kwargs, &block)
    i = allocate()

    # Extra instance setup code here

    i.send(:initialize, *args, **kwargs, &block)
    return i
  end
end

class Test < SuperClass
  def initialize
    puts "No args here"
  end
end
```

The class `SuperClass` basically "reimplements" the default `new` method so that some extra initialization can happen before `initialize`.

Now, the following works just fine:

```
t = Test.allocate
t.send(:initialize, *[], **{}, &nil)
```

However, this does not:

```
t = Test.new
```

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
from (pry):7:in `initialize'
```

It fails on this line in `SuperClass`:

```
i.send(:initialize, *args, **kwargs, &block)
```

But apparently it only fails if called within the `new` method. I have confirmed that `args == []`, `kwargs == {}` and `block == nil`.

Is anybody able to explain this?

---

Ruby version:

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
```

<sub>Please refrain from suggesting that I don't overload `Class.new`. I am aware I can use `Class.inherited` and `Class.append` for the same result. This question is only about why the call to `initialize` fails.</sub>

Comment: It appears to work with `i.send(:initialize, *args, **kwargs, &block)` changed to `i.send(:initialize, *args, &block)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Indeed. It also appears to behave identically as far as I can see.

Comment: It appears the reason is that `**kwargs` converts zero or more keyword arguments to a hash, so if there are none you get an empty hash, which is of course an argument. You can test that easily enough.

Comment: @CarySwoveland But `send(:initialize, *[], **{}, &nil)` works elsewhere, no arguments are sent to `initialize`. This issue just happens within the `Class#new` method. Have we found a bug?

Comment: @cremno So 2.2.0 still has the *correct* behavior, while later versions has the *wrong* behavior because of a lazy segfault fix? :P

Answer (score 4):

Let's examine a simpler example, especially because the problem isn't as specific as the question and its title make it look like but see for yourself.

```
def m   # takes no arguments
end
m(**{}) # no argument is passed
h = {}
m(**h)  # an argument is passed => ArgumentError is raised
```

This inconsistency was introduced in 2.2.1 by a commit intended to fix a segmentation fault involving `**{}` ([Bug #10719](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10719)). The commit special-cases `**{}` to not pass an argument. Other ways like `**Hash.new` and `h={};**h` still pass an empty hash as argument.

Previous versions consistently raise `ArgumentError` ([demo](https://eval.in/449802)). I could be wrong but I believe that's the intended behavior. However it may or may not be the one actually wants. So if you think double-splatting an empty hash shouldn't pass an argument (like `**{}` at the moment) and therefore work similar to splatting an empty array, there is an open issue about that ([Bug #10856](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10856)). It also mentions this relatively new inconsistency.

Comment: That explains a lot, thanks. This stuff is by no means intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `*args` will capture all arguments including keyword arguments, in case you don't need to reference `kwargs` separately in the `new` method:

```
class SuperClass
  def self.new(*args, &block)
    i = allocate

    # Extra instance setup code here

    i.send(:initialize, *args, &block)
    i
  end
end
```

Comment: I had no idea `new` as an instance method was a thing... Now I'm really confused as to how all these methods fit together. Why can it be both a class method and an instance method?

Comment: I guess the class method internally just calls the instance method `new` as a convenience, so you can properly access `initialize` for example. Ruby magic ;-)

Comment: Still though, how come I allocate a new instance *from* an already allocated instance, and return that instance? This still isn't making sense to me

Comment: Ok, I just tested this in Ruby 2.2.3, and `Class#new` is never called :S

Comment: It didn't make sense to me either and I must apologize for pointing you in the wrong direction. The blog post ist just wrong, and indeed you need to override `initialize` and use `send`. The second part of my answer is still valid though. Editing...

Comment: The blog post isn't wrong. There's no actual `Class.new` since it's `Class#new` and it works because `Class` is an instance of `Class`.

Comment: OK let me say it differently: the post is misleading in the context of this answer, because you are not operating on Class. So I have removed it.